# Vaadin 14 Loading records to grid when scrolling fast

Tags: scroll, grid, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

When i'm scrolling fast through grid then i see for a while blank records and after some time they are filled and if i scroll again to the begining then records that were previously filled are loading too. I noticed that if I scroll fast up and down few times that everything is loaded and i can start scrolling without blank records. I don't use lazy loading in this grid it has about 300 records. I'm using Vaadin 14.4.0 version.

Is there any way to load everything at start, or at least don't load records that were filled before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setPageSize(DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE );
```

Is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin does not load all data at once to the client to improve performance. While at the backend the data may be loaded all at once, Vaadin sends only the records of the visible rows (plus some more) to the client (browser).

Imagine you have a dataset of 1.000.000 records with 20 columns. The data transfer and client sided rendering would be enormous.